# how to change gridview row color in runtime?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am using a grid view and inside it im using a dropdown list

My gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdUser" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" CaptionAlign="Left" OnPageIndexChanging="grdUser_PageIndexChanging" OnSorting="grdUser_Sorting" PageSize="5" CssClass="table table-hover table-striped table-responsive" DataKeyNames="Email">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCFF" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#009933" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Medium" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
        <PagerSettings FirstPageText="First" Mode="NumericFirstLast" LastPageText="Last" PageButtonCount="4" NextPageText="" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#CC66FF" HorizontalAlign="Right" VerticalAlign="Middle" ForeColor="Black" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAct" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlAct_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Action" Text="imtiaz" >Action</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Activate" Text="imtiaz">Activate</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Block" Text="imtiaz">Block</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Delete" Text="imtiaz">Delete</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

now there is a condition when i click activate the selected row color should be changed

my code is

```
protected void ddlAct_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
    {
        DropDownList ddlAct = (DropDownList)sender;
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)ddlAct.Parent.Parent;
        int idx = row.RowIndex;
        string Email = grdUser.DataKeys[idx]["Email"].ToString();

        //string Email = ((Label)row.Cells[0].FindControl("Email")).Text;
        DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)row.Cells[0].FindControl("ddlAct");
        var ddlvalue = "";

        if (ddl.Text.ToString() == "Activate")
        {
            ddlvalue = "Approved";

        }
        else if (ddl.Text.ToString() == "Block")
        {
            ddlvalue = "Blocked";
        }
        else
        {
            ddlvalue = ddl.Text.ToString();
        }
        string query = "Update Users set Status ='" + ddlvalue + "' where E_Mail='" + Email + "'";



        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        GetDataTable();

        lblMsg.Visible = true;
        lblMsg.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        lblMsg.Text = "Status is :  Account is " + ddl.Text.ToString();
    }
}
```

i have to change color inside selected index changed only.
please help

Comment: Minor improves: use `ddlAct.NamingContainer` instead of `ddlAct.Parent.Parent` and `row.FindControl("ddlAct")` instead of `row.Cells[0].FindControl("ddlAct")`.

Comment: According to the issue, it's not clear. Why can't you use: `row.BackColor = whatevercolor`

Comment: Did you try `grdUser.SelectedRow.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Aqua;`?

Comment: @both yes i have tried but it doesn't work

Comment: Try setting the color in the RowDataBound event.  That works for me

Answer (score 0):

I have done this for multiple projects

```
 Public Sub MyGridView_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        Dim checkCell As String = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("Label11"), Label).Text
        If checkCell = 0 Then
            e.Row.Cells(11).BackColor = Drawing.Color.Green
            e.Row.Cells(11).ForeColor = Drawing.Color.White
        ElseIf checkCell > 0 And checkCell < 11 Then
            e.Row.Cells(11).BackColor = Drawing.Color.Yellow
        ElseIf checkCell > 10 Then
            e.Row.Cells(11).BackColor = Drawing.Color.Red
            e.Row.Cells(11).ForeColor = Drawing.Color.White
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

The FindControl("Label11") refers to my databound objects in the aspx page. and the e.row.cells(11) is the column number that i want to highlight. these values can be changed to choose any column or find controls. This even is called on databind, so a databind might be what you need to get your row color to update.